# R - strtoi strange behavior to get week of year

Tags: r, date, format

I use `strtoi` to determine the week of year in the following function:

```
to.week <- function(x) strtoi(format(x, "%W"))
```

It works fine for most dates:

```
> to.week(as.Date("2015-01-11"))
[1] 1
```

However, when I'm trying dates between `2015-02-23` and `2015-03-08`, I get `NA` as a result:

```
> to.week(as.Date("2015-02-25"))
[1] NA
```

Could you please explain to me what causes the problem?

Comment: @rmuc8, not quite since this is asking why his approach doesn't work, rather than how to do it generically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an implementation that works:

```
to.week <- function(x) as.integer(format(x, "%W"))
```

The reason `strtoi` fails is by default it tries to interpret numbers as if they were octal when they are preceeded by a `"0"`.  Since `"%W"` returns `"08"`, and 8 doesn't exist in octal, you get the NA.  From `?strtoi`:

> Convert strings to integers according to the given base using the C function strtol, or choose a suitable base following the C rules.
>
> ...
>
> For decimal strings as.integer is equally useful.

Also, you can use:

```
week(as.Date("2015-02-25"))
```

Though you may have to offset the result of that by 1 to match your expectations.

Comment: You explanation seems incomplete to me. It is the fact that there is a leading `"0"` in the result from format.Date that causes the problems.  `format(as.Date("2010-02-26"), "%W")
[1] "08"` . The function `strtoi` does not interpret "10" as a decimal 8.

Answer (score 5):

you can slightly modify your code like this

```
to.week <- function(x) strtoi(format(x, "%W"), 10)
```

and use base 10.

Comment: Thank you, it's useful to know!